# MySql- set as default value not working

Tags: mysql

I create table

```
CREATE TABLE `delivery_week_repo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_sale` float(6,2) unsigned DEFAULT '0.00',
  `from_sent` float(6,2) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

And when I add string where `from_sale` without value, then it's value becomes `NULL` rather than `0.00`.

Comment: Unrelated - `DEFAULT NULL` is redundant

Comment: Try declaring the column `NOT NULL`.

Comment: I guess you need to Declare the column as 'NOT NULL'

Comment: "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Comment: Whatever, my crystal ball suggests you are not omitting the column in your insert statement. `DEFAULT` means "use this value when no value is set", not "force that all rows have this value no matter what I tell you later".

Comment: `from_sale` is a *float* column and yet you use a string default. Use `0` as the default. What is your `INSERT` statement? What value are you trying to insert? A number or a string that has to be converted? A NULL or empty string perhaps?